# Location of fill tube for Nissan Pintara auto transmission fluid

Tags: transmission, automatic-transmission, nissan

Where on a 2.4lt 1989 Nissan Pintara do you put the transmission fluid? I cannot seem to find where it would go and my vehicle is not changing gears properly.

Comment: Did it come with an owner's manual?

Comment: No it did not and i have tried to google to find out and cannot seen to find it anywhere

Comment: I googled for: `NISSAN PINTARA 1989-1992 WORKSHOP` and found a number of relevant hits. Just be careful what you download. Only download PDFs; never run a "downloader" or an "installer" to get at a file. If it's legit, they'll link to the PDF directly.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, the [workshop manual](https://carmanuals2.com/get/nissan-stanza-1989-repair-manual-50851) makes no mention of a fill plug.

After draining out the old transmission fluid via the drain plug and reinstating it, one option is to introduce the new ATF through the dipstick channel.

Page AT-85 of the manual says that the transmission takes 6.8 L of ATF.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a location to refill the ATF on this vehicle.

You will need to take it to a shop where they have special pumps to remove and replace the current ATF in your transmission.

Comment: It has a drain plug

Comment: @Zaid. But not a fill point.  It needs to be pumped out

Comment: Couldn't you just pull out the dipstick?